# Initializing classes in module for namespace

Tags: python

There is a module `car.py`.

There are engine and tires, and I want them (theirs methods and properties) to be accessible as

```
car.engine.data
# and
car.tires.data
```

So file `parts.py` looks like

```
class engineClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'foo data 1'

class tiresClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'foo data 2'

engine = engineClass()
tires = tiresClass()
```

And now after `import car` I can access them as I want - `car.engine.data`

Is it a right thing to do for this task?

Comment: ... And just what task would *that* be?

Comment: What are you using these classes for?

Comment: for delimiting `type1` and `type2`. They are different, but close enough for being in one module.

Comment: I changed "parts" to more concrete "car".

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make your purpose any clearer.

Comment: Agree, but it is just a 'basic' stuff, it is hard to make it very concrete, because if I know how to ask it right, there was no question in the firs place. Nevertheless, the concrete answer is found  quickly, so the question is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure... I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but you could skip initializing the classes in the case you've shown. Just do:

```
class type1(object):
    data = 'foo 1'

class type2(object):
    data = 'foo 2'
```

Whether or not that makes sense in the context of what you're doing, I have no idea...

For that matter, you could just do

```
class Container(object):
    pass

type1, type2 = Container(), Container()
type1.data = 'foo 1'
type2.data = 'foo 2'
```

Or any other number of similar things... What are `type1` and `type2` representing?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I was looking for. I thought you should always initialize instance.

Comment: If you need an instance - create it. But you can also use the class, which is an object (instance) itself. In the case above `data` is a static variable of the class (class attribute)